# How to get cell value by cell coordinate?

Tags: php, phpexcel

The below works fine to **set** value:

```
$this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue('hello world');
```

But why the below returns null?

```
$this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();
```

I know this works fine:

```
return $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, 1)->getValue();
```

But I want a way to get value by cell coordinate, as getValue of "A1" instead of using (0,1)

Comment: You're `return`ing the value from the line that you say works well, but there's no `return` in the line you say returns null; so perhaps you should be returning that as well

Comment: @MarkBaker How I didn't notice this! How silly!! Thanks Mark. Please put that as the answer I'll tick it.

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#retrieving-a-cell-value-by-coordinate):

## Retrieving a cell value by coordinate

To retrieve the value of a cell, the cell should first be retrieved from the worksheet using the getCell() method. A cell's value can be read using the getValue() method.

```
// Get the value fom cell A1
$cellValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();
```

This will retrieve the raw, unformatted value contained in the cell.

If a cell contains a formula, and you need to retrieve the calculated value rather than the formula itself, then use the cell's getCalculatedValue() method. This is further explained in .

```
// Get the value fom cell A4
$cellValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A4')->getCalculatedValue();
```

Alternatively, if you want to see the value with any cell formatting applied (e.g. for a human-readable date or time value), then you can use the cell's getFormattedValue() method.

```
// Get the value fom cell A6
$cellValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A6')->getFormattedValue();
```